# Bitcoin Transfer Not Done

Tags: sendtoaddress

[image]

I send 0.043 bitcoin to the 1Fhpf5bA95zBPzsPezozDYf9h2jCYD31TA address. But it didn't reach to this address. When I click the address on TX page you can view the pic that Sent : 0 BTC
What's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you included also says: "Received: 0.0434 BTC", which is consistent with what I see. The transaction has thirty confirmations, and 0.434 BTC were signed over to the address 1Fhpf5bA95zBPzsPezozDYf9h2jCYD31TA.

In case you mean that your wallet doesn't show the transaction yet, perhaps your wallet is still synchronizing?

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the 6 confirmations. It looks like it is there: https://blockstream.info/address/1Fhpf5bA95zBPzsPezozDYf9h2jCYD31TA
Just a bit patience.